# Referencing function input variables from other input variables

Tags: python

I want to make some function like below:

```
def test_fn(var1: int = 1, var2: int = var1+1):     
    return var1, var2
```

(and the function above simply does not work which would raise
`NameError`)

Is there any smart way of referencing `var2` from `var1` as input variable without adding or running other lines before this function?

Thanks in advance  :D

Comment: You would have to put that logic inside the body of the function.

Comment: @larsks ah, I wanted to avoid that way, but I guess I have to stick with that lol xD
Thx!

Comment: Python calculates default values when the function is defined, not when it's called. So this is impossible.

Comment: This is proposed in [PEP 671](https://peps.python.org/pep-0671/) which isn't accepted or rejected yet. Maybe it'll be possible in the future.